# Ford fiesta diesel brake pedal hard

Tags: ford, diesel, fiesta, brake-pedal

I have ford fiesta diesel 1.4. I am facing a problem.   Month ago I  felt that when i apply brake fast in an emergency pedal got hard. It took some time to get normal. Today when i start the car, feel that brake pedal is hard. Please advise...

Answer (score 2):

If the pedal is so hard that it has little effect on the brakes it is most likely a vacuum issue.

On diesels there is a separate vacuum pump connected to the brake servo via a pipe. Check the pipe work and servo for any obvious leaks. If none are present pull the pipe off the pump when the engine in running and check for vacuum.

You can do this my using a gauge or by simply putting your finger over the end of the port on the pump and seeing if there is a large amount of suction. If there is a vacuum put the pipe back on and disconnect the next joint along and check there and so on. If you have vacuum present at the pipe that connect to the servo you have an servo issue.

If there is no vacuum out of the pump, remove the pump and check the keyway/gear that drives it, if this is all good the vacuum pump is no good.

If this is the 1396/8cc PSA engine it is very common for the plastic elbow leaving the pump to snap off, the pump is located on the right hand side of the engine driven of the camshaft.